# A fixed window for NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa

I create NSOutlineView with my own data source. Now problem is that while expanding an item, it expands upwards and rightwards whereas I have mentioned the frame.
How to fix this expansion? I want a fixed window rather.

```
    NSOutlineView *     outlineview;    ///< Outline view.
    OutlineDataSource * datasource;     ///< Data source.


//Create the outline view.
outlineview     = [[NSOutlineView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect (10, 430, 400, 800)];
[outlineview setDelegate:self];

//Create the data source.
datasource  = [[OutlineDataSource alloc]init];

//Set the data source.
[outlineview setDataSource:(id<NSOutlineViewDataSource>)datasource];
    NSTableColumn *c    = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"Cases"];

//Create a column.
[c setEditable: NO];
[c setMinWidth: 450];
[outlineview addTableColumn: c];
[outlineview setOutlineTableColumn: c];


//Add the outline view to the window.
[view addSubview: outlineview];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proper constraints in Interface Builder, including the proper priority.

In your case, the outline view and/or the enclosing scroll view should have a lower priority than the window's width.

It may take a bit of experimenting, and getting all the constraints right can be a bit of a challenge the first times.

If you don't use Interface Builder, you can read about your options in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1).

The debugging advice in the same document is very useful, too.

Comment: I am not using Interface Builder. How to set this property programmatically?